# Android - Media Player, How to play audio from blob:file:///52f826aa-0aed-4c35-3675-f464554c9bcc

Tags: java, android, html, cordova, audio

How to use Media Player to stream audio file?

it's fine when i use Cordova HTML5 Audio tag,
but when i tried to use Android Native to play the audio it fails.

The example url:

```
blob:file:///52f826aa-0aed-4c35-3675-f464554c9bcc
```

I have tried to remove the blob,but still fails

```
file:///52f826aa-0aed-4c35-3675-f464554c9bcc
```

The error is :

```
java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
```

My java code:

```
    String stream_url = "blob:file:///52f826aa-0aed-4c35-3675-f464554c9bcc";
    String stream_file = stream_url.substring(5);
    try {
        if (mMediaPlayer == null) {
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        } else {
            try {
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
                mMediaPlayer.reset();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(stream_file); // Go to Initialized state
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (Throwable t) {

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Aren't blobs only within the browser: https://superuser.com/questions/948738/what-is-the-blobhttp-prefix-and-where-can-i-learn-more-about-this so if you are going to use Android Java framework media player you'll have to provide an appropriate endpoint.

Comment: oh i see, thanks for clarification